# Couldn't get the required result from an array. It only display the first letter instead of display the whole string

Tags: php, arrays

The original array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment4.jpg
    [1] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment5.jpg
)
```

I transferred this array via input hidden field for ajax. Here is the input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="inv_slider[]" value="<?php print_r($photos); ?>" />
```

On the other side, I got this array

```
Array ( 
  [0] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment4.jpg 
  [1] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment5.jpg 
      )
```

when I `var_dump($cv)` this array, I get the following result

```
array(1) { 
 [0]=> string(207) "Array ( 
      [0] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment4.jpg 
      [1] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment5.jpg 
      ) 
  " }
```

I just want url's in this array.
I tried

```
foreach($cv as $image){ 
            echo $image;
        }
```

but again get this result

```
Array ( 
 [0] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment4.jpg 
 [1] => http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment5.jpg 
)
```

I also tried

```
foreach($cv as $image){ 
            echo $image[0];
        }
```

and got a single character "A".
I am using wordpress CMS.

Comment: cv is just a string of the result of `print_r` on an array, its not anything you can parse with php.

Comment: so how to get the url's from that string?

Comment: maybe some sort of regex. but I don't understand why your data is in that format to begin with?

Comment: How do you declare and build the first array? please add your code

Answer (score 1):

Associated arrays are composed of key => value pairs separated by comma. You left off the commas and since URLs are strings, you need to wrap your array values with single or double quotes. Don't use quotes for numerics keys or values, in your case the keys. In fact don't use the square brackets neither.

Try This:
    $cv = Array ( 0 => "http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment4.jpg", 1 => "http://redhawk-studio.com/demos/rizwan/it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/investment5.jpg" );

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be on this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="inv_slider[]" value="<?php print_r($photos); ?>" />
```

You are printing out the whole array and therefor you are getting it in the value as a string, so you actually have a string with the word ARRAY and the elements.

You would be better using Json to move the array by using `json_encode` and `json_decode`, so in your HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="inv_slider[]" value="<?php echo json_encode($photos); ?>" />
```

and in your PHP where you get that field value just decode back from json to array and you can access all elements

```
$slider = json_decode($_POST['inv_slider']);
```

As i don't know the rest of your code i assume that you send the form by POST.

Comment: yes, I sent the form by post and the above solution didn't work. Now I have found the solution. I just created the array of input fields for each array element of $photos. Thank for your time.